# Android app calling customer service number

Tags: android, android-permissions

What is the best option to implement a function that allow the user to call the customer service number in app?

In iOS, this is easy, just say `UIApplication.shared.open("tel:xxxxxxx")` will do. It will show a small dialog to allow the user to call or not, and shows the number to the user clearly so the user knows this is a free number.

However in Android I need to add `android.permission.CALL_PHONE`, but this is a dangerous permission, when the user install the app they will see a message "this app may cost you money".

In API 23+ we can request permissions at runtime, but the document says we still need to add the user permission to request it at runtime.

So, what is the best option we can have? We don't want the user being scared by a harmless feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in documentation, CALL_PHONE permission is used for making calls from app itself. It's possible to hide it from user and yes, it's dangerous.

> CALL_PHONE Allows an application to initiate a phone call without
>   going through the Dialer user interface for the user to confirm the
>   call.

But you may always make calls using dialer without any extra permissions.

```
Intent callIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:xxxxxxx"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```